# ContextBroker Vectors UPDATE with unchanged value causes ONCHANGE subscription notification

Tags: fiware-orion

I have a JSON formatted as this one:

```
{
"contextElements": [
    {
        "type": "environment",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "labMax",
        "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "users",
            "type": "vector",
            "value": [{"userId":"0001", "status":"0"},{"userId":"0002", "status":"0"}]
        },
        {
            "name": "rooms",
            "type": "vector",
            "value": [{"room1": [ {"id":"room1"}, {"owner":"1"}]},{"id":"room2"}, {"owner":"2"}]
        },
        {
            "name": "sensors",
            "type": "vector",
            "value": [
          {"sensor1": [ {"id":"1"}, {"location":"room1"},{"value":"11"},{"status":"ok"}]},
          {"sensor2": [ {"id":"2"}, {"location":"room1"},{"value":"22"},{"status":"update"}]}
          ]
        }

        ]
    }
],
"updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

I have also a subscription **ONCHANGE** on the attribute "sensors" and when I update it, without changing any value inside the vector, it causes a notification. Probably this is a wrong behaviour because a subscriber should be only notified when a value changes. On the other side, if I use *strings* or *integer* as attributes values, it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Up to Orion 0.16.0 at least, this is a known behaviour. [An issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/643) has been openend in the Orion github.com repository about it.

**UPDATE**: since Orion 3.11.0 (released on January 29th, 2024) this problem is solved.

By the way, you are highly encouraged to use [NGSIv2 API](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/orion-api.md). The NGSIv1 shown in the question post is deprecated and could be removed soon.

Comment: Answer has been edited to include additional information. This issue is now solved.